# Why does charge 'stick' to the Gaussian surface?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law, conductors

I'm currently studying Gauss's Law and interaction of the charge with different Gaussian surfaces etc. But here's something that I couldn't understand. Why does a charge 'stick' to a Gaussian surface?

For example: when we put some charges over a Gaussian surface. They spread themselves evenly over the Gaussian surface? Why don't they just fall down (maybe because they have no mass?)? or not interact with the Gaussian surface at all? Why don't they just stay where they are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should never speak of arranging charges *on* a Gaussian surface, because a Gaussian surface isn't real.  It's an imaginary bubble that we draw around a charge distribution *in our minds*, not an actual physical object.

When you put charges on the surface of a *conductor*, they spread out and arrange themselves evenly over the surface.  You may have gotten the two concepts confused.

Comment: Thankyou, But if a conductor is electrically neutral, like in the case of a neutral charged sphere. Why does the charge stay on the conductor? Why doesn't it float away?

Comment: If that is your question, then you should ask it in a new question post or edit the current one. I'm sure you will receive some enlightening answers.

Comment: Be aware that you'll probably need to understand a bit about solid state physics in order to get or rather understand a meaningful answer for that specific question